# How to display page in zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I want to display simple static page

my Controller

```
class WaitListController extends BaseController
{

    public function indexAction()
    {  
        $viewModel = new ViewModel();
        $Waitlistform = new \Webadmin\Form\WaitListForm();

       // return $viewModel->setVariables(array("customerform"=> $Waitlistform));
        return $viewModel->setVariables(array('userName','mujahed'));
        //return $viewModel;
    }

}
```

and my page is index.phtml in form folder but its not working  giving following error

```
/var/www/html/restaurant/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php:498
```

Message:

```
Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "merchant/wait-list/index"; resolver could not resolve to a file
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 /var/www/html/restaurant/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/View.php(205): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#1 /var/www/html/restaurant/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/View.php(233): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#2 /var/www/html/restaurant/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/View.php(198): Zend\View\View->renderChildren(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#3 /var/www/html/restaurant/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/View/Http/DefaultRenderingStrategy.php(102): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#4 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy->render(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#5 /var/www/html/restaurant/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#6 /var/www/html/restaurant/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('render', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Array)
#7 /var/www/html/restaurant/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php(352): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('render', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#8 /var/www/html/restaurant/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php(327): Zend\Mvc\Application->completeRequest(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 /var/www/html/restaurant/public/index.php(46): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#10 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unable to render template
This error means, that you didnt created view script for action. Do you have index.phtml inside good filepath? Show us your file structure.

Good file path for skeleton app:

```
module/Application/view/application/index/index.phtml
```

so for you i think its should be:

```
module/YOUR_MODULE_NAME/view/application/wait-list/index.phtml
```

Remember to use wait-list instead of WaitList. ZF convert path from camel case.

If you learning ZF2 use skeleton application, you will catch everything a lot faster

Comment: Can you please provide skypeId?